# Services don't communicate internally in Docker

Tags: asp.net, docker, redis

I am trying to run an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application (`REDIS` + `RabbitMQ` + `NGINX`) on Docker.

When I upload these containers via `docker-compose`, these services work and are even accessible by Windows, since they are mapped by "HostPORT: ContainerPORT".

However, when testing the App itself, .NET informs in console that it was not possible to connect to the REDIS, for example.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
  Connection id "0HLDGDJNAEB9E", Request id "0HLDGDJNAEB9E:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
  StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. SocketFailure on PING.
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./nginx/nginx.dockerfile
      context: .
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - production-network
    depends_on:
      - "wordSearcherApp"

  wordSearcherApp:
    image: wordsearcherapplication
    container_name: wordsearcherapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WordSearcher/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - production-network
    ports:
      - "61370"
    volumes:
      - repository:/repository
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - rabbit

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - production-network

  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    networks:
      - production-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:15672"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

networks:
  production-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  repository:
    driver: local
```

For Connection in C#, i use this connectionString `localhost:6379`

How can i do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `redis:6379` instead of `localhost:6379`.

Docker-Compose will use the name you've defined for a service in the docker-compose.yml file as the hostname for its container.